# Interfacing Docker containers apps with an existing Apache web server

Tags: apache, docker, redirect

I am fairly new to Docker and I have some trouble to understand how to make my "contained" apps accessible from the internet.

[**my current configuration**] two web sites (in /var/www/html) + standard Apache + some tweeking I would like to be applied to everything new I deploy (headers CSP based rewriting, SSL certificate renewal with *Certbot*, etc etc). I am fairly happy with my current conf.

[**my two apps**] Both are standalone applications (only requiring a db).

-[official wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) image. (-> new domain name)

-a django based app packed with a gunicorn server based on [this tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application) (-> subdomain of an existing domain )

[**the issue**] If I bind both apps on, say, ports 8080 and 8000, browsers wont be able to reach it, for DNS servers do not handle ports (from what I understood, correct me if I am wrong). If I bind then on standard ports, I'll have a conflict with my existing Apache.

How would you deal with it? Can I redirect to containers' internal ip with a [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) of some kind? Is there a cleaner-easier-safer way to do it?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub.mydomain.io
    Redirect "/" "http://172.17.0.2/"

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.zarebski.io.com.log
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can't you just proxy pass towards ports 8080 and 8000?

Answer (score 1):

In case of multiple applications running on different ports and different local IP addresses the recommended method is using [Reverse Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Basically you configure your apache to forward requests to those services, i.e.:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub.mydomain.io
    ProxyPass "/wordpress" "http://172.17.0.2:8080/"
    ProxyPass "/django" "http://172.17.0.2:8000/"

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.mydomain.io.com.log
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have multpile external domain you can use Name Based [Virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work but I still can't get css and js (classical, from what I read). Struggling with RewriteRule clauses [sources](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it took me a while to figure things out, for there was two main corner cases. I'll stick to one case: the *wordpress image*

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName new_domain.eu
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/

    <Location />
            AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
            SetOutputFilter proxy-html
            ProxyPassReverse /
            Substitute "s|http://localhost:8081/|https://new_domain.eu/|i"
            RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
    </Location>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/new_domain.eu/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/new_domain.eu/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

[**First of all**], I could not access container from their **local ip** (i.e 172.7.0.3:80, not sure why), so I used the localhost port defined while setting the container up:

```
docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=thePassWord --name wordpress --link wordpressdb:mysql -p 8081:80 -v "$PWD/html":/var/www/html -d wordpress
```

[**secondly**] the tricky part was, then, to handle properly relative urls (e.g. some/path/to/css), for these were not accessible. Apparently, this is a [well known issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy). This part was the longest: things changed a lot around Apache 2.4 and the syntax is not well documented. Basically,

```
Substitute "s|http://localhost:8081/|https://new_domain.eu/|i"
```

replace all urls in html so that relative resources (css, js, png, etc etc) could be properly accessed.

[**possible improvements**] I am not quite happy with port 8081 being visible from the external world. It means that the app could be accessed from this very port, bypassing the rules I setted up in **apache.conf**. I fixed the issue by adding an **iptables rule**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8081 -j DROP
```

Not quite elegant so if anyone has a suggestion, let me know.

\//_